# Clean URLs with mod_rewrite - when directory exists?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've found this piece of code to get clean URLs, e.g. rewrite domain.com/start/ to domain.com/start.php

This works fine unless there is a directory with the same name. I have no idea what I can do about this. I want Apache to still rewrite the URL, even if there is a directory with the same name (as long as the file exists).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another `RewriteCond` to include directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```